# html classes are changed to Attributes

Tags: php, html, css

i'm trying to send an html code to database and then show the code in index.php 
this is what i use to send the html code to DB:

> when i quote the attributes i get sql syntax error

```
$result = "          <li>
                <a href=$Link class=external item-link item-content>
                  <div class=item-media><img src=$f_image class=lazy lazy-fade-in style=border-radius: 10px; width=42px height=42px></div>
                  <div class=item-inner>
                    <div class=item-title>
                      $Name <span class=test-bull>&bull;</span>
                      <div class=item-footer>$Info</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=item-after></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>

              ";

$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (test) VALUES ('$result')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
}else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and this is what i use to show the code in index.php:

```
<?php

      $sql = "SELECT test FROM table1";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row ["test"];
 }
 } else {
    echo "0 results";
}

              ?>
```

now as you can see there is more than one class in my html code:

```
<a href=$Link class=external item-link item-content>
```

the problem is when i get the html code from database and show it in index.php the class are changed to attributes like this:

```
<li>
                <a href="test" class="external" item-link="" item-content="">
                  <div class="item-media"><img src="img/2ff4e.aa.png" class="lazy" lazy-fade-in="" style="border-radius:" 10px;="" width="42px" height="42px"></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-title">
                      test <span class="test-bull">•</span>
                      <div class="item-footer">test</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-after"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
```

those two class item-link and item-content are now item-link="" and item-content=""

what i did wrong? what i have to change/do?

sorry for my english

Comment: <a href="test" class="external" item-link="" item-content="">

Comment: item-link and item-content is a class but became something else item-link="" and item-content=""

Comment: Oh those are classes? Then that's because you didn't quote them to begin with and they are treated as attributes: `class='external item-link item-content'`.

Comment: when i quote them i get sql syntax error

Comment: what is prepared statements and how can i use it ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes. Try this:

```
$result = '          <li>
            <a href="'.$Link.'" class="external item-link item-content">
              <div class="item-media"><img src="'.$f_image.'" class="lazy lazy-fade-in" style="border-radius: 10px; width=42px height=42px"></div>
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">
                  '.$Name.' <span class="test-bull">&bull;</span>
                  <div class="item-footer">'.$Info.'</div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-after"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Always enclose your variables inside a string between curly brackets like `href={$Link}` so the compiler can determine exactly where is the variable and how to convert it value to string, specially when variable is not alone (meaning any other digit, letter or symbol is directly in contact with the variable like the equal sign before `$Link`)

Comment: Besides that, review html tags, you always need to determine attribute values with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = "This is double quotes, I need html class :) simple <div 
class='class_name_under_single_q'> Content </div>";

$result = 'This is Single quotes, I need html class :) simple <div 
class="class_name_under_double_q"> Content </div>';

<?php
   $result = "<a href=".$Link." class=".external item-link item-content.">";
?>
```

if you use double quotes then use single quotes under double quotes .
But if you use single quotes then use double quotes under single quotes .

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you always have to use quotes (' or ") around the value of html-attributes when the value contains a space or one of these characters: " ' ` = < >. To avoid the sql error, you have to mask the characters that may disturb in SQL context (you have always to do this when you inserting values into an SQL string):

```php
$result = '[…]<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($Link).'" class="external item-link item-content">[…]';
$html = $conn->real_escape_string($result);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (test) VALUES ('".$html."')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
```

(assuming that `$conn` contains a mysqli-connection) The call of `htmlspecialchars()` is necessary because you change the context of the string in `$Link` to html.

prepared statements are also possible:

```php
$result = '[…]<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($Link).'" class="external item-link item-content">[…]';
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (test) VALUES (?)";
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $result);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```